# How to fix error "Duplicated build" on "readthedocs"?

Tags: read-the-docs

On *readthecods* I am trying to build a project, but I get the error

```
Error
Duplicated build.
```

How to fix that problem?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue and after some research I found [this pull request](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/pull/7420) indicating that one just has to wait for 5 minutes before trying again.

Indeed after waiting a few minutes I was able to trigger a rebuild without getting the error.

A question that is not yet clear to my is why it was considered a duplicate in the first place, as there was some (admittedly small but relevant) modification on the repository.